# Unable to resume execution of a background process

Tags: process, background-process, jobs

I tried to install git through the command line,

`sudo apt install git`.

I put that process into the background by pressing **Ctrl-Z**. This also stops the process's execution so I tried to resume with

`bg 1`

but `jobs` yields *stopped*.

How can I resume the execution of this process?

---

Update: I put the process in the foreground but unfortunately I don't get an output of the execution progress. Is there any way to send a signal to `apt` to get the progress as an output?

Comment: What is the output of `stty -a | grep -o '.tostop'` in that terminal?

Comment: `-tostop` @HaukeLaging

Comment: You mean you tried to resume with `fg` instead of `bg`, right?

Comment: I tried both @Quasímodo

Comment: You could attach to the stopped process with `strace` before you run `bg %1`: `strace -p $PID` In order to see what happens. Whether the process is started at all.

Comment: I'll try that @HaukeLaging. The process was started and I remember it reached 43% of its progress. I guess I could just `Ctrl-Z` and restart it again but it really bugs me that I cannot resume it. On addition what would happen if instead of *git* I was installing a much larger program, wouldn't `Ctrl-Z` had left unnecessary  files that I wouldn't have the ability to remove later?

Comment: Btw here is the output of strace `--- stopped by SIGTTIN ---` which means somehow a stop(?) signal was sent to `apt` @HaukeLaging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process was **expecting input** from the terminal and apparently I missed any output messages in this regard. The problem was revealed after inspecting the process with `strace` (thanks @Hauke Laging) yielding,

```
--- stopped by SIGTTIN ---
```

A description of this signal is provided in [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html),

> A process **cannot read from the user’s terminal while it is running as
>   a background job**. When any process in a background job tries to read
>   from the terminal, all of the processes in the job are sent a SIGTTIN
>   signal. The default action for this signal is to stop the process.

After I inserted some random input the execution continued until termination.

Answer (score 1):

And option is to use screen:

```
$ screen      # to create the screen
$ sudo apt install git
ctrl-A d      # to detach the screen
$ screen -r   # to reattach
```

Comment: I guess this helps monitor the progress of the execution?

Comment: Running the applications under screen means that the session does not terminate – only the now-defunct terminal gets detached – so applications don't even know the terminal has detached, and allows the user to reattach the session later and continue working from where they left off.